# Gradlew: no source code available for type "userclass"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I've been following this tutorial on creating a flappy bird clone using libgdx http://www.kilobolt.com/zombie-bird-tutorial-flappy-bird-remake.html
and while the android and desktop version works fine, when I try to create the html version I run into trouble.

I have read the libgdx documentation on reflections which discussed this issue https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reflection but when I try to follow what was mentioned I still get the error. I have also read through most other questions about problems similar to mine, but I'm not entirely sure if I've implemented the solutions to their problems correctly or not because I still get the same errors.

This is what I currently get when I run `./gradlew html:dist`

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:html:clean
:html:addSource
:core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes UP-TO-DATE
:core:jar UP-TO-DATE
:html:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
1 warning
:html:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:html:compileGwt
Compiling module com.gsoo.wirebird.GdxDefinition
   Validating units:
      [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/home/gavinsu/Documents/wireBird-master/core/src/com/gsoo/wirebird/wbGame.java'
         [ERROR] Line 11: No source code is available for type com.gsoo.wbHelpers.AssetLoader; did you forget to inherit a required module?
         [ERROR] Line 12: No source code is available for type com.gsoo.screens.SplashScreen; did you forget to inherit a required module?
   [ERROR] Aborting compile due to errors in some input files
:html:compileGwt FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':html:compileGwt'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 21.749 secs
```

I don't want to make this post too long so I'll post my entire code in a zip here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B29c3qREvyioSjlFUVA2MzE3VTA/view?usp=sharing
(If this is not allowed I'll edit it in.)

How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I was able to figure this out the next morning. Turns out I needed to add the source path to my other classes in the *.gwt.xml with: 
`<source path="path/to/class" />`
this fixed my errors and allowed it to compile fully.

Comment: What is the path relative to?